# Using PHPUnit in Zend Framework version 0.7

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

We have an application developed using Zend Framework preview version 0.7. Now I would like to write unit test its controllers / logic files.

The logic mostly deals with the database and for database I am using my own wrapper.

Did anybody try unit testing an application on top of Zend Framework version 0.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

I was the Project Manager of Zend Framework 0.7.  That Preview Release you mention was made in [January 2007](http://www.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-0.7.0-released-td8440612.html) -- about 26 months ago!  It was a very early release, and ZF has been refactored many times since then.

You really should never have employed such an early, raw version of ZF in a project that would last this long.

You should upgrade to ZF 1.6 or newer, and use the [unit testing component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.html) provided.

---

Regarding your comment, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.migration.html for information on upgrading from older releases.  This only covers `Zend_Controller`, not other components of ZF.  This is the only guide I'm aware of.  There's no specific "0.7 to 1.7" guide.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes. You are right it is a very early version of Zend Framework. We are using Zend Framework version 1.5 in some of our projects. 

So does Zend provide any documentation on upgrading from such an old version of Zend Framework?

Comment: Thanks Bill. I will look into this document and I hope I would be able to upgrade our application easily.